# PHP and MySQL echoing out a Table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I've done this before, and it worked.  I am trying to echo out specific rows on my database in a table.  Here is my code:

```
<?php    
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx") or    
die ("Hey loser, check your server connection.");    
mysql_select_db("xxx");    
$quey1="select * from `Ad Requests`";    
$result=mysql_query($quey1) or die(mysql_error());    
?>

<table border=1 style="background-color:#F0F8FF;" >    
<caption><EM>Student Record</EM></caption>    
<tr>    
<th>Student ID</th>    
<th>Student Name</th>    
<th>Class</th>    
</tr>

<?php    
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){    
echo "</td><td>";    
echo $row['id'];    
echo "</td><td>";    
echo $row['twitter'];    
echo "</td><td>";    
echo $row['why'];    
echo "</td></tr>";    
}    
echo "</table>";    
?>
```

It gives me no errors, but It just shows a blank table with none of these rows.

**My Question:  How come this wont show any rows in the table, what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Just checking: do you mean blank output or a blank table?

Comment: I mean this:  http://prntscr.com/elbl7

Comment: You forgot to open a new table row tag `tr` for every database row.

Comment: check sql is correct or not because some time you miss small thing then too it didn't show output and keep it blank

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array()` returns a numerically-keyed array, e.g. `$row[1]`. You want `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead. Or use `mysql_fetch_row()`, which fetches a dual-array - numerical AND string keys.

Comment: While that *is* an issue, it's not the cause of no rows showing.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array fetches both by default. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: @vulcan: empty table still means there's rows/cells - they're just empty and collapsed down to 0-size. a viewing of the page source will undoubtedly show a long series of empty `<tr><td></td><td></td>...</tr>`

Comment: @MarcB It will undoubtedly *not* show a long series of that exact format, as there is no opening `<tr>`, so no table rows would be shown even if they aren't empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<tr><td>";

echo $row['id'];

echo "</td><td>";

echo $row['twitter'];

echo "</td><td>";

echo $row['why'];

echo "</td></tr>";

}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

I think tr's and td's where not correct

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to open a new table row for every row of your database.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<tr>"; // Your code lacks this

echo "</td><td>";
```

Currently, your outputted HTML will have a lot of table row closures `</tr>` but no openers, hence the lack of table rows in your resulting visual output.